# What's the correct Maven dependencies to use Spring JMS and ActiveMQ?

Tags: spring, maven, jetty, activemq-classic, spring-jms

This is quite a common problem and I have found plenty solutions that do not work for me on the web. I am declaring:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And jetty plug-in

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

But I keep on getting the following exception when issuing "mvn jetty:run":

> org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class
>   [org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler] for
>   namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core] not found; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler

What would be the correct maven dependencies to run Jetty, ActiveMQ and Spring JMS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need dependency on xbean-spring

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
  <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
  <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to have those dependencies as 'provided' dependencies to your webapp then make them dependencies of the jetty-maven-plugin itself, you can add  tags inside of the  decl of the jetty-maven-plugin.  Assuming you validated the classes your missing exist in those dependencies or their transitive deps.